# jQuery event.PreventDefault not working in User Defined Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, events

I am creating a function which will take in a URL and then display that URL in a light box. I am having trouble with event.preventDefault() in my function though, it says it is not a function in the error console.

I have tried explicitly passing event to the function but that simply runs the function on page load rather than when clicking

Here is my code:

```
    // Function to display widget
    function displaySportsWidget(event, iframeURL) {
        // Prevent Default Event Handler
        event.preventDefault();

        // Build iFrame HTML
        var iframe = '<iframe src="' +  iframeURL + '" ></iframe>';         
        var html = iframe;

         // Inject HTML to Generate Widget
        $('.leagues-wrapper').html(html);

        // Display Overlay
        $('.leagues-overlay').css('display', 'block');
    };

    // Event handlers. Pass iFrame URL into function depending on link clicked
    $('.leagues-link.league-table').on('click', displaySportsWidget('http://www.example01.com'));
    $('.leagues-link.league-form').on('click', displaySportsWidget( 'http://www.example02.com'));
```

Comment: You are *calling the function* (which yields a non-function result) when you need to *pass a function [uncalled] as the callback*.

Comment: Can you change your event name to e only in parameter? I think that is conflicting with global event variable.

Comment: @SimpleMan: That's not the problem with the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code

```
$('.leagues-link.league-table').on('click', displaySportsWidget('http://www.example01.com'));
```

**calls** `displaySportsWidget` and passes its return value into `on`, exactly the way `foo(bar())` **calls** `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`.

If you want to hook up an event handler, you don't call it, you just refer to it. In your case, you can do that like this:

```
$('.leagues-link.league-table').on('click', function(e) {
    displaySportsWidget(e, 'http://www.example01.com');
});
```

Or if you're open to changing the order of arguments in `displaySportsWidget`:

```
function displaySportsWidget(iFrameURL, event) {
    // ...
}
```

...then you can use `Function#bind`:

```
$('.leagues-link.league-table').on('click', displaySportsWidget.bind(null, 'http://www.example01.com'));
```

`Function#bind` creates a new function that, when called, calls the original function with a given `this` value (in our case, we don't need any specific one, so I'm passing `null`) and any arguments you gave `bind`, followed by any arguments that were given to the bound function. So we'll get the URL (from the `bind` call) followed by the event object (from when the handler is called).

`Function#bind` isn't on really old browsers like IE8. If you need to support them, jQuery's `$.proxy` does something similar:

```
$('.leagues-link.league-table').on('click', $.proxy(displaySportsWidget, null, 'http://www.example01.com'));
```

Answer (score 0):

While calling your method you are not passing event as parameter along with image url .so if u pass event as parameter while calling.then your code is going to work.
Thank you